# Are there any canon reasons for why evil beings put up with the certainty of damnation?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, planescape

**Is there any written canon material that explains why evil beings in the D&D multiverse put up with the certainty of damnation?**

Here's a thing that's always bothered me about the "default universe" in D&D.

Adventurers and powerful wizards and clerics traverse the lower planes from time to time. And there they discover what awaits the souls of evildoers: they're transformed into lemures, larvae and worse, and spend eternity being tormented by more powerful extra-planar beings.

This is a fundamental truth in D&D, something that will have been verified by countless numbers of spellcasters and conversations with planar beings.

So, given that it's known with absolute certainty that an eternity of low-grade misery awaits anyone with an evil alignment, why would any sentient creature choose to be evil?

I appreciate that some very few go on to become transformed into more powerful creatures and can begin to climb the ladder of power once again. But with an eternity of souls to choose from and a limited number of slots in the hierarchy, the chances seem so remote as to fail as a mitigating factor.

If, as other answers have suggested, it's because evil is an absolute concept in D&D, and evil things are just "born evil", wouldn't it have a major impact on their outlook on life, a constant source of worry and despair?

Has anything canon ever been written about this?

Comment: to the person who voted to close, I believe the fact this is asking for written canon material saves it from being opinion based

Comment: Asking for canon barely saves this question - the answer so far are disregarding that requirement. Only answer this with documented D&D lore, not your own suppositions.

Comment: @mxyzplk RPG:SE seems to have become far harder on supposition than when I last visited. Is this intentional, or am I mistaken?

Comment: It is intentional. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Comment: @mxyzplk Interesting and useful, thanks. So if I'd rephrased this question along the lines of "how have you handled this paradox in your game sessions", it would have passed muster as "good subjective"?

Comment: Does edition matter or is this a how-have-things-changed question?

Comment: @HeyICanChan It's edition agnostic, although if there have been changes in how this is interpreted I'd be interested in knowing what they are.

Comment: I suggest removing the Planescape tag unless you want answers to reference that material. It might be good to specify in the question the cosmology that interests you--not all settings use, for example, [The Great Wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)#Great_Wheel_cosmology).

Comment: Not really, but please take extended questions about what's on topic to meta.

Comment: OK I'm going to have to close this a minute because of the answers coming in.  Can you tune the question to focus even more on "I want reasoning for this based on written D&D lore?" I know you mention it but the answerers aren't getting the hint. Then I'll reopen and delete all answers not quoting published sources.

Comment: @mxyzplk Thanks - closing is the right decision but I'm going to pass on re-phrasing it. The answers suggest there is little/no canon reference to go by. And I need to understand better why it's not a "good subjective" question in order to frame it as one based on experience.

Comment: OK up to you. Your question is valid as it stands, it's just pulling low quality answers, but if you want to go a different direction with it that's fine.  I'm not sure it's possible to do an experience-based Q around this though, see http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5357/what-kinds-of-alignment-questions-are-on-topic

Comment: Do not answer in comments.

Comment: Given that, throughout history, countless Christians have been very sure of eternal damnation and gone ahead and been bandits and murderers and whatnot anyway, why do you even need a D&D-specific explanation? Sometimes people do bad things for short-term gain despite knowing full well it'll be bad for them in the long term. Why would D&D characters be any different? As far as I can tell, this question should stay closed, as it concerns psychology rather than anything game-specific.

Comment: @GMJoe The difference is that D&D lore has the concept of evil creatures doing evil because they're evil and they were born that way and that's that, and other simplifications for game design or storytelling reasons, rather than complex individuals committing evil because they're down and out or need to pay the rent or whatever. Bear in mind D&D has evil creatures literally born as evil incarnate.

Comment: @doppelgreener It has both of those concepts, though you make a fair point that "evil creatures do evil because they're evil and they were born that way and that's that" would only be found in a D&D-specific answer. OK, you've persuaded me that this isn't entirely off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While good and evil, or law and chaos, are fairly absolute from a DM and player's point of view, those concepts are not always black and white to the creatures of the game world. Going back to the AD&D 2e Planescape setting concepts, creatures that are true to their alignment go the planar realm of their deity when they die; in other words, their religion's "heaven".

Planeswalker's Handbook (TSR2620, 1996) pg 8: "Petitioners are the spirits of deceased primes and planars who inhabit the plane of their deity or alignment. Petitioners take many shapes but are usually indistinguishable from other folks, at least at first. They don't remember their former lives and only vaguely reflect their previous personalities; they're shaped into whatever form their power or their alignment requires. About the only thing they have to work toward is the hope of attaining union with their power or plane. They never leave their home planes for fear of permanent dissolution."

While the eternal realm of Gruumsh might seem nasty and hellish to human commoners, to orcs, it's quite a grand afterlife.

To simplify the Norse idea of Valhalla, those with noble souls go off to an endless eternity of fighting, feasting and otherwise partying it up. This is quite different than the Christian idea of heaven, but to Vikings, earning a place there was a lofty, noble and goodly goal.

Comment: Can you reference any written material to back up your point about Planescape setting concepts?

Comment: Planeswalker's Handbook (TSR2620, 1996) pg 8:
"Petitioners are the spirits of deceased primes and planars who inhabit the plane of their deity or alignment. Petitioners take many shapes but are usually indistinguishable from other folks, at least at first. They don't remember their former lives and only vaguely reflect their previous personalities; they're shaped into whatever form their power or their alignment requires. About the only thing they have to work toward is the hope of attaining union with their power or plane. They never leave their home planes for fear of permanent dissolution."

Comment: @DarvaShriver First, you should edit anything that's part of your answer into your answer; Comments aren't permanent. Second, that's not entirely conclusive; Petitioners have no memories of their living lives, and having a desire to become one with their plane of residence doesn't necessarily mean they like it there - When such desires are documented, they often seem to take the form of "unnatural" compulsions. See, for example, the careful bookkeeping of Outlands petitioners balancing their aligned deeds, or the cannibalistic struggles of larvae in the lower planes.

Comment: @GMJoe  It's a useful comment, although assays it should be edited into the answer. I'm most interested in "they don't remember their lives" - since that would be a possible motivating factor.

Comment: What the passage implies to me is that spirits of the deceased go to the plane their religion and alignment are attuned to, not some objective hell where they are punished for their sins. The part about not remembering their mortal lives suggests that when the living commune with them through prayer (spells), the petitioners now at one, or close to it, with the ideals of their faith or alignment, are unlikely to tell them "it sucks here", partly because they don't remember enough about mortal life to make a comparision.

Comment: @DarvaShriver *Speak with dead*, the one published spell that allows a living person to communicate with a dead one without actually tracking down the petitioner, is clarified in the planescape setting as actually contacting that person's memory core where it drifts in the astral, rather than the petitioner in the afterlife. That said, you do make a reasonable argument; You should clarify that in your answer.

Answer (score 5):

**Answer: A mix of the personal ego, overestimating one's abilities, underestimating the environments of the lower planes, being too ambitious for their own good and corrupting influences not telling the complete truth. And it is possible to go from evil to good, but it's rare.**

Being evil and going to hell is kinda like being smart and going to MIT. You're so used to being the smartest son of an owlbear in the room, that being surrounded by people just as smart as you are is quite the shock because it never happened before. Except with, you know, evil.

Only the insane, the cartoonish and those the Internet calls "edgelords" consider themselves captial e Evil. All others consider themselves in the right, or do what they want without caring for others, or lack self-reflection to see what they are or what they are capable of. Nobody is the villain in their own story: everyone sees themselves as te hero. Or at least the protagonist, but most definitely NOT the antagonist.

And with ambition and ego comes the occational smartass who thinks that they're good enough to overcome the challenges of hell and become a Pit Lord, or even a Lord of Hell in their own right. And that imp you summon and have you help out sure as hell ain't gonna tell you that you're so full of crap you can expell a manure golem: they will act like the good lackey they are, tell you what to do to gain more power and give you backrubs while encouraging you to perform heinous acts. *I mean, you're amazing at these sort of things, so someone with your ambition should, what, spend a decade at most as a lesser devil, another decade to get through the ranks of the greater devils and as a Pit Lord less than halfway into the third decade. So don't you worry about that, champ, and keep doing what you do. Oh, and by the way you should totally have all those orc babies killed. They're just going to grow up into jerks who want to pillage your lands.*

But when your life's over and the local orc barbarian gives you a viking crewcut with his battleaxe and you go to hell, the imp just claims your soul as something he liberated then prances off towards the horizon (tap-dancing is strictly banned in Hell). He gets kudos and you get to spent time in the pit of tormet until your personality is eroded away until but a shell of your soul remains, and you're turned into a moving pile of dung.

You see, Hell is not a nice place to be. This is why its travel agents do not 100% accurately and factually tell its prospective travelers what it's like or how often you can expect to be used as a pincuchion by a spinagon. They play it up, tell what a nice place it can be if only someone with the right skills and knowledge walks around, and that all Pit Fiends were once lowly lemures, something that might very well happen to you. It's like playing the lottery with your soul, except that if you win you become a being of immense power and if you lose eternal torment awaits you. So they make people think that they can run the place because they don't consider the option that there are more badass and malevolent beings in Hell than them. So they sign the pact, they get the power they want in life, get the money, get the women... but then the local adventurers show them their stabs, the pact person dies, have their personality (and with it their knowledge and skills) stripped and turned into an evil bag of rotting meat.

And even then, if you do make it up to the higher ranks you're just going to be surroundedy fiends more evil than thou, and they'll gladly gang up on you and tear you apart. Even if you do make deals yourself with fellow fiends they're going to turn on you eventually, unless you turn on them first. But if you do that too often nobody's going to trust you and make deals with you.

So in short: No, you are not badass enough to overcome the politics of Hell. If you try you're just gonna end up in a crappy form without your memories, or if you're really lucky in a less crappy form. And as always, remember the first rule of making deals with fiends:

*Do not make deals with fiends.*

If you are looking for more on Baator, I suggest either *Planes of Law - Baator* if you want something Planescape specific, or *Fiendish Codex II: Tyrands of the Nine Hells* and the *Manual of the Planes* (both 3.5e and 4e) if you want to read more.

As for being evil, it's kind of a mixed bag. Most fiends would not dream of giving up their power to become some nobody (in their eyes) and be bossed around without ever trying to take over themselves. There are cases of it happening though: there is a chaotic evil wizard living in the first layer of Celestia, currently undergoing redemption (3.5e Manual of the Planes), and the succubus Fall-From-Grace is a decent person, despite being born from the raw powers of chaos and evil (Planescape: Torment). But this is VERY RARE, and the fall from good to evil happens a LOT more than overcoming evil and turning to good. Plus, not everyone on either side would happily accept people from the other, even if they could redeem/torment them.

Comment: The question asks for written canon material - this appears to consist purely of your own opinion, which therefore doesn't answer the actual question

Comment: I see at least 2 question marks in question text. One of them corresponds to the question of "why evil beigns beign evil when everyone knows what awaits them afterlife". This question answer this one pretty accurately, in my opinion.

Comment: I found this answer interesting - although I'm not sure I agree with the premise. So it partially answers my question. What I'm hoping for is something a bit like this, but with references to published material to back up the POV.

Answer (score -2):

For gaming purposes the easy way to do deal with this is portray long term evil as putting the short terms needs for oneself over the long term needs of others. And use the tropes centered around the seven deadly sins as a broad canvas on which to model the behaviors and attitudes of the NPC.

You can apply this to the level of divines gods, to inhabitants of the mean streets.

The fundamental issue of the seven deadly sins (Lust, Gluttony, Greed, Sloth, Wrath, Envy, Pride) is that they are ultimately destructive to a individual in of themselves. The individual committing these sins put themselves before others. Contrast the above seven sins with the seven virtues;  Humility, Charity, Kindness, Patience, Chastity, Temperance, and Diligence.

Reasons for committing these sins on a long term basis can range from

- I have a good reason and the ends justify the means.
- I deserve some pleasure.
- So what I am damned! I will just live life to the fullest until then.
- Good is doing it wrong, I can do better.
- I deserve what due to me. (the cause of Lucifer's fall from heaven.)

Think of any lame excuse you ever heard from someone to justify stupid or harmful actions and you will be able to generate more motivations for evil beings do be doing what they are doing despite the reality of damnation.

And most boils back to the fact the individual is thinking only of themselves and is deliberately not willing to thing of the impact of their actions on other people.

Also understand if you get too deep into this then you will start running into age old philosophical questions that been debated for centuries along with the variations found across various cultures.

As for being born evil, several religions teach that everyone is born with sin that it is only by true belief and/or right action that one can be rescued from this condition. Many Christian sects have original sin. Several eastern religions have the idea of a cosmic progression over multiple lives leading to perfection.

For gaming purposes many religions share the idea that without X that you are destined to do evil in the form of sin. Today most present this more of a lack of knowledge issues rather than as a person is going to do horrible bad things for the rest of his days without X. However in the fantasy world of D&D, it could literally mean that without X the sentient individual will indeed horrible bad things.

I am being vague about X because that highly dependent on time, place, and culture.